# How to insert a "pop-out image thumbnail" into a cell in Numbers?

Tags: graphics, numbers

I have a Numbers document where I would like to insert images into each cell in one of the columns, in one of my data tables. The images are quite large, so I would like to insert the images as a thumbnail, and have them "pop out" when I click or mouse-over the image, so that I can see the full-size image. How can I accomplish this effect? Is this at all possible?

It was fairly simple to add an image to a cell via drag-and-drop from Finder, by using the "Image Fill" and "Scale to Fill" options. However, in order to see details in the image, I would need to make the cells very large. I'm looking for a way to "zoom in" or make the image "pop out" somehow, either on mouse-over or when I click on the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of back and forth, trial and error, I have come to the conclusion that this is not yet possible in Numbers, and that Excel is still superior in this regard.